# Grep for value in string over x milliseconds

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I know how to `grep` and find all the lines in a file that contain a simple string:

```
cat my_log.log | grep 'Completed 200 OK in'
```

That returns results similar to the following:

```
various info... Completed 200 OK in 250ms various info...
various info... Completed 200 OK in 112ms various info...
various info... Completed 200 OK in 1000ms various info...
various info... Completed 200 OK in 6000ms various info...
various info... Completed 200 OK in 33ms various info...
various info... Completed 200 OK in 100ms various info...
```

I'd like to take it a step further and only return the lines where the milliseconds (ms) is *over* 1000.

Is this possible with grep?  Other posts suggest using `sed` but I'm curious if it is possible to do this with `grep`.

Comment: It should not be tackled with grep, nor with sed, as neither support arithmetic operations and trying to do numeric comparisons with regexps is extremely cumbersome and error-prone. Just use a tool that can do arithmetic, e.g. awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sure**

The grep  command comes with an option `-E` which enables extended regular expressions in your pattern.

Then you just have to look for a 4 digit value with the regex `[0-9]{4}`

```
cat my_log.log | grep -E "Completed 200 OK in [0-9]{4}ms"
```

If you need 4 or more digits just use the range `{4,}` instead of `{4}`

```
cat my_log.log | grep -E "Completed 200 OK in [0-9]{4,}ms"
```

Comment: Grep defaults to using regular expressions, but `-E` enables "extended regular expressions" where you have to escape fewer/other things: `grep '.\{4\}'` and `grep -E '.{4}'` are equivalent.

Comment: Huh.. I didn't know that - I've always used `-E` when working with grep and regex... Thanks for that @BenjaminW.

Comment: Drop the `cat`, no need for it.

Comment: That will print the line where ms is equal to 1000ms, not just when it's over 1000 as asked for in the question, and you can't easily use that regexp approach  for arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is awk for both a regexp and arithmetic comparison, e.g. with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/Completed 200 OK in ([0-9]+)/,a) && (a[1] > 1000)' file
various info... Completed 200 OK in 6000ms various info...

$ awk 'match($0,/Completed 200 OK in ([0-9]+)/,a) && (a[1] >= 1000)' file
various info... Completed 200 OK in 1000ms various info...
various info... Completed 200 OK in 6000ms various info...

$ awk 'match($0,/Completed 200 OK in ([0-9]+)/,a) && (a[1] >= 112)' file
various info... Completed 200 OK in 250ms various info...
various info... Completed 200 OK in 112ms various info...
various info... Completed 200 OK in 1000ms various info...
various info... Completed 200 OK in 6000ms various info...
```

or if you don't have GNU awk then with any awk:

```
$ awk '{ms=$0} sub(/.*Completed 200 OK in /,"",ms) && (ms+0 > 1000)' file
various info... Completed 200 OK in 6000ms various info...
```